# Installing Gentoo on HP DL380 G4 fails at installing Kernel sources

Tags: kernel, gentoo

I'm trying to install Gentoo amd64 on an [HP DL380 G4](https://support.hpe.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c00244802). I've managed to get to the [Configuring the Linux Kernel](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Handbook:AMD64/Installation/Kernel) section in the Gentoo Installation Handbook. After using this command:

`emerge --ask sys-kernel/gentoo-sources`

I get the following output:

```
(chroot) livecd / # emerge --ask sys-kernel/gentoo-sources

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild  N     ] sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2  USE="readline -libedit -static" 
[ebuild  N     ] sys-kernel/gentoo-sources-4.14.65  USE="-build -experimental -symlink" 

Would you like to merge these packages? [Yes/No] yes

>>> Verifying ebuild manifests

>>> Emerging (1 of 2) sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo
 * Fetching files in the background.
 * To view fetch progress, run in another terminal:
 * tail -f /var/log/emerge-fetch.log
 * bc-1.06.95.tar.bz2 BLAKE2B SHA512 size ;-) ...                                                                                                                                      [ ok ]
>>> Unpacking source...
>>> Unpacking bc-1.06.95.tar.bz2 to /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work
>>> Source unpacked in /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work
>>> Preparing source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95 ...
 * Applying bc-1.06.95-void_uninitialized.patch ...                                                                                                                                    [ ok ]
 * Applying bc-1.06.95-mem-leak.patch ...                                                                                                                                              [ ok ]
>>> Source prepared.
>>> Configuring source in /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95 ...
./configure --prefix=/usr --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --datadir=/usr/share --sysconfdir=/etc --localstatedir=/var/lib --disable-dependency-tracking --libdir=/usr/lib64 --with-readline --without-libedit
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/lib/portage/python3.6/ebuild-helpers/xattr/install -c
checking whether build environment is sane... yes
checking for gawk... gawk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc
checking for C compiler default output file name... configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details.

!!! Please attach the following file when seeking support:
!!! /var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95/config.log
 * ERROR: sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo failed (configure phase):
 *   econf failed
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *               ebuild.sh, line  124:  Called src_configure
 *             environment, line 2172:  Called econf '--with-readline' '--without-libedit'
 *        phase-helpers.sh, line  718:  Called __helpers_die 'econf failed'
 *   isolated-functions.sh, line  121:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *          die "$@"
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95'

>>> Failed to emerge sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2, Log file:

>>>  '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/temp/build.log'

 * Messages for package sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2:

 * ERROR: sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo failed (configure phase):
 *   econf failed
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *               ebuild.sh, line  124:  Called src_configure
 *             environment, line 2172:  Called econf '--with-readline' '--without-libedit'
 *        phase-helpers.sh, line  718:  Called __helpers_die 'econf failed'
 *   isolated-functions.sh, line  121:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *          die "$@"
 * 
 * If you need support, post the output of `emerge --info '=sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo'`,
 * the complete build log and the output of `emerge -pqv '=sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2::gentoo'`.
 * The complete build log is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/temp/build.log'.
 * The ebuild environment file is located at '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/temp/environment'.
 * Working directory: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95'
 * S: '/var/tmp/portage/sys-devel/bc-1.06.95-r2/work/bc-1.06.95'
```

What could the problem be?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Consider asking over at https://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You should check CFLAGS variable in make.conf first:

```
cat /etc/portage/make.conf
```

It should be like this:

```
CFLAGS="-march=native -O2 -pipe"
```